# Using buffered reader does not give Runtime error but using Scanner gives on Online judge?

Tags: java

I was doing [this](http://poj.org/problem?id=2418) question. I submitted the following code that uses a scanner to read input.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main{ 

public static void main(String[] args)throws java.lang.Exception{
    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    int trees = 0;
    while(true){
        String tree = cin.nextLine();
        if(tree==null){
            break;
        }
        trees++;
        if(map.containsKey(tree)){
            map.put(tree, map.get(tree)+1);
        }else{
            map.put(tree, 1);
        }
    }
    for(String key : map.keySet()){

    }

    Iterator<String> itr = map.keySet().iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        String tree = itr.next();
        System.out.print(tree + " " );
        double percent = (double)map.get(tree)/trees*100;
        System.out.format("%.4f\n", percent);
    }

}
}
```

But I get a runtime error. But when I submit the same code but this time I use a buffered reader, then my answer gets accepted. Is this a problem with the judge or am I missing some feature of java's input output routines.

Should I use a buffered reader or a scanner to read data more robustly?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main{ 

public static void main(String[] args)throws java.lang.Exception{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    int trees = 0;
    while(true){
        String tree = br.readLine();
        if(tree==null){
            break;
        }
        trees++;
        if(map.containsKey(tree)){
            map.put(tree, map.get(tree)+1);
        }else{
            map.put(tree, 1);
        }
    }
    for(String key : map.keySet()){

    }

    Iterator<String> itr = map.keySet().iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        String tree = itr.next();
        System.out.print(tree + " " );
        double percent = (double)map.get(tree)/trees*100;
        System.out.format("%.4f\n", percent);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I get a runtime error. The judge just says that there is a runtime error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the contracts on the methods you're using. [`BufferedReader#readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) returns `null` if it's at EOF; [`Scanner#nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) "throws `NoSuchElementException` - if no line was found." If you want to use `Scanner`, your loop conditional needs to be checking `cin.hasNextLine()`.

Comment: yeah!! thanks. Answer got accepted when I checked the condition of cin.hasNextLine().